# Colocar resultado de cuenta por id Dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy realizado una consulta a un archivo php mediante ajax en el cual me toma dos valores de una tabla impresa dinamicamente en el cual realiza todo bien solo que el resultado lo coloca en otro lugar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '#formulario_modificar', function() { 
        //Obtenemos datos formulario.
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var idprovisorio = $('#idp').val();
        //AJAX.
        $.ajax({  
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'modificar_ajax.php',
            data:  data, 

            success:function(data) { 
              console.log(data);
              $("#"+idprovisorio).html(data);
            }  
        });
        return false;
   });
});
```

```php
<form id="formulario_modificar" class="formulario">
    <input type="hidden" name="idp" id="idp" value="<? echo $row['idprovisorio'] ?>">
    <td class="td_table">
        <input name="cant" class="input_table" value="<? echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
    </td>
    <td class="td_table">
        <input name="prec" class="input_table" value="<? echo $row['precio'] ?>">
    </td>
    <td id="<? echo $row['idprovisorio'] ?>">
        <? echo $row['total'] ?>
    </td>
    <input type="submit" name="cargar" value="Cargar" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Osea me toma el valor de `cant` y `prec` bien pero cuando imprime mas de un producto el resultado me lo coloca en la primer celda en lugar de colocarlo en la celda que debe ir, si actualizo la página los resultados se acomodan. Porque podrá ser?

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos

Comment: Si el ID es un número, jQuery te va a causar problemas, intenta evitarlo

Comment: Hola Pablo. Muchas gracias! Voy a verlo

Comment: Concuerdo con  @PabloLozano, quizá debas poner algún string y concatenarle el id provisorio para que te lo tome como texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias! a esta linea: <td id="<? echo $row['idprovisorio'] ?>"><? echo $row['total'] ?></td>, Cambie el id por "table-id-$row['idprovisorio'], cuando realiza la cuenta del pirmer registro impreso el resultado aparece bien, pero cuando realiza la cuenta de los demas cambia el resultado del primer registro, este cambio no lo hace en la base de datos ya que si actualizo me coloca los resultados bien. Tal vez esta mal planteado lo que estoy realizando